# How to Update d3 force directed graph dynamically in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2

I have this ***VueJS*** code generating ***d3*** force directed network node on mount using json call.
I'm trying to update the network graph with new nodes and links using the same json call and after calculating differences, I want it to add/remove nodes/links accordingly but I can't figure out how to do it.

- I already tried to look for examples of dynamic updated of d3 force directed graphs. I actually did find some vue js + d3 examples but non with dynamic updates such as [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/agnjunio/fd86583e176ecd94d37f3d2de3a56814) which shows how to change the data of the graph and causes the simulation to get restarted but this is not what I look to accomplish.
- I've been trying for days to Adapt proper d3 js code from examples into vue js but with no success.
- couldn't find any examples with Vue.js and d3 v5 (found some with v4).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      graph: null,
      simulation: null,
      color: d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10),
      settings: {
        strokeColor: "#29B5FF",
        width: 100,
        svgWidth: 960,
        svgHeight: 600
      },
      radius: 50,
      tooltip: d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip2").html(""),
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var that = this;
    var initData = '{"nodes":[{"id":1,"ip":"100.64.1.118","name":"PCRF","description":"Policy and Charging Rules Function","image":"https://i.imgur.com/mpAqPb4.png"}],"links":[]}';
    var initBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(initData)], {
      type: "application/json"
    });
    var initUrl = URL.createObjectURL(initBlob);
    d3.json(initUrl, function(error, graph) {
      console.log(graph);
      if (error) throw error;
      that.graph = graph;
      that.simulation = d3.forceSimulation(that.graph.nodes)
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(that.graph.links).distance(300).strength(1))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(that.settings.svgWidth / 2, that.settings.svgHeight / 2))
        .force("xAxis", d3.forceX(that.settings.svgWidth / 2).strength(0.4))
        .force("yAxis", d3.forceY(that.settings.svgHeight / 2).strength(0.6))
        .force("repelForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000).distanceMax(300).distanceMin(300));
    });
    d3.interval(function() {
      var interData = '{"nodes":[{"id":1,"ip":"100.64.1.118","name":"PCRF","description":"Allot Policy and Charging Rules Function","image":"https://i.imgur.com/mpAqPb4.png"},{"id":2,"ip":"100.64.1.119","name":"Client","description":"Diameter Client","image":"https://i.imgur.com/NsUvLZb.png"}],"links":[{"id":1,"source":1,"target":2,"type":"OKAY"}]}';
      var interBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(interData)], {
        type: "application/json"
      });
      var interUrl = URL.createObjectURL(interBlob);
      d3.json(interUrl, function(error, graph) {
        console.log(graph);
        that.updateGraph(graph);
      });
    }, 5000);
  },
  methods: {
    fixna(x) {
      if (isFinite(x)) return x;
      return 0;
    },
    updateGraph(graph) {
      var that = this;
      that.graph = graph;
      //TODO Nodes
      var newLinks = graph.links;
      newLinks.forEach(function(d) {
        d3.select("#l" + d.id)
          .attr("class", function(d2) {
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              return "connected"
            } else {
              return "disconnected"
            }
          })
          .on("mouseover", function(d2) {
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "3px");
            } else {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "2px");
            }
            t_text = "<strong>" + d2.source.ip + " <-> " + d2.target.ip + "</strong>";
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              t_text += '<br>Connection Status: <font color="green">' + d.type + '</font>';
            } else {
              t_text += '<br>Connection Status: <font color="red">' + d.type + '</font>';
            }
            that.tooltip.html(t_text)
            return that.tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
          })
          .on("mousemove", function() {
            return that.tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(d2) {
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "2px");
            } else {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "1px");
            }
            return that.tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
          });
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    nodes: function() {
      var that = this;
      if (that.graph) {
        var node = d3.select("svg").append("g").attr("class", "nodes").selectAll("g")
          .data(that.graph.nodes).enter().append("g")
          .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", function dragstarted(d) {
              if (!d3.event.active) that.simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
              d.fx = d.x;
              d.fy = d.y;
            })
            .on("drag", function dragged(d) {
              d.fx = d3.event.x;
              d.fy = d3.event.y;
            })
            .on("end", function dragended(d) {
              if (!d3.event.active) that.simulation.alphaTarget(0);
              d.fx = null;
              d.fy = null;
            })).attr("fill", "white");
        var defs = node.append("defs");
        defs.append('pattern')
          .attr("id", function(d, i) {
            return "my_image" + i
          })
          .attr("width", 1)
          .attr("height", 1)
          .append("svg:image")
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            return d.image
          })
          .attr("height", that.radius)
          .attr("width", that.radius)
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", 0);
        var circle = node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", that.radius / 2)
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return "url(#my_image" + i + ")"
          })
          .attr("id", function(d) {
            if (d.id == "p0") {
              return "mainNode"
            } else {
              return d.id
            }
          })
          .attr("stroke", "#494b4d")
          .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "3px");
            //sets tooltip.  t_text = content in html
            t_text = "<strong>" + d.name + "</strong><br>IP Address: " + d.ip
            that.tooltip.html(t_text)
            return that.tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
          })
          .on("mousemove", function() {
            return that.tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
          })
          .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "2px");
            return that.tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
          });
        node.append("text")
          .style("fill", "black")
          .attr("dx", 0)
          .attr("dy", that.radius - ((that.radius / 10) - 3) * 5)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.name + " - " + d.ip;
          });
        return node;
      }
    },
    links: function() {
      var that = this;
      if (that.graph) {
        return d3.select("svg").append("g")
          .attr("class", "links")
          .selectAll("line")
          .data(that.graph.links)
          .enter()
          .append("line")
          .attr("id", function(d) {
            return "l" + d.id
          })
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              return "connected"
            } else {
              return "disconnected"
            }
          })
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "3px");
            } else {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "2px");
            }
            t_text = "<strong>" + d.source.ip + " <-> " + d.target.ip + "</strong>";
            if (d.type == 'OKAY') {
              t_text += '<br>Connection Status: <font color="green">' + d.type + '</font>';
            } else {
              t_text += '<br>Connection Status: <font color="red">' + d.type + '</font>';
            }
            that.tooltip.html(t_text)
            return that.tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
          })
          .on("mousemove", function() {
            return that.tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            if (d.type == 'good') {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "2px");
            } else {
              d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width", "1px");
            }
            return that.tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
          });
      }
    },

  },
  updated: function() {
    var that = this;
    that.simulation.nodes(that.graph.nodes).on('tick', function ticked() {
      that.links
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          return that.fixna(d.source.x);
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return that.fixna(d.source.y);
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return that.fixna(d.target.x);
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return that.fixna(d.target.y);
        });

      that.nodes
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + that.fixna(d.x) + "," + that.fixna(d.y) + ")";
        });
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
I created <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/tsp48yL3/1/" target="_blank">this fiddle</a>.
<div id="app">
  <div class="svg-container" :style="{width: settings.width + '%'}">
  <svg id="svg" pointer-events="all" viewBox="0 0 960 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <g :id="links"></g>
   <g :id="nodes"></g>
  </svg>
 </div>
</div>
```

it's working with **d3.v4**. I tried changing to **v5** but it doesn't work (maybe can someone shed some light).
Would be happy if anyone can point me to the right direction or help me with the implementation.

I'm trying to add nodes and remove them exactly like in this demo [here](http://soccomb.appspot.com/news).

there you can see new nodes generated without the whole simulation restarting which makes it look very smooth.